# Screw theory for kinematics/dynamics of mechanisms

Tags: kinematics, dynamics, mechanism, screw-theory, mechanical-engineering

Is screw theory commonly used for general kinematics/dynamics of mechanisms (not just robotics)?  I'd be interested in anything that covers the types of mechanisms you would find in a typical kinematics/dynamics of mechanisms course, but from a screw-based perspective.

If so, can someone provide me with references (preferably books, but if not then articles or anything else)?